# Javascript - convert array multi level to single level

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I am trying to map a complex object array document to a single level array. For example

```
const data = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Beauty",
        "children": {
            "0": {
                "id": 5,
                "parent_id": 1,
                "name": "Dermatology",
                "code": "dermatology",
                "status": 1,
                "updated_at": 1678262275,
                "created_at": 1678262275
            },
            "1": {
                "id": 7,
                "parent_id": 1,
                "name": "Plastic surgery",
                "code": "plastic_surgery",
                "status": 1,
                "updated_at": 1678262275,
                "created_at": 1678262275
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Healthiness",
        "children": {
            "0": {
                "id": 11,
                "parent_id": 2,
                "name": "Ophthalmology",
                "code": "ophthalmology",
                "status": 1,
                "updated_at": 1678262275,
                "created_at": 1678262275
            },
            "1": {
                "id": 13,
                "parent_id": 2,
                "name": "Pediatrics",
                "code": "pediatrics",
                "status": 1,
                "updated_at": 1678262275,
                "created_at": 1678262275
            },
        }
    }
]
```

The objective is to turn the array into something like this regardless of the complexity.
Basically, if loop through each item in the array and get children item and add parent_name for them

```
[
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Dermatology",
        "parent_id": 1,
        "parent_name": "Beauty"
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Plastic surgery",
        "parent_id": 1,
        "parent_name": "Beauty"
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "Ophthalmology",
        "parent_id": 2,
        "parent_name": "Healthiness"
    },
    {
        "id": 13,
        "name": "Pediatrics",
        "parent_id": 2,
        "parent_name": "Healthiness"
    },
]
```

My code here, but result not I expect.

```
let cusData = data
          .map((item) => item.children)
          .flat()
          .map((child) => {
            return {id: child.id, name: child.name, parent_id: child.parent_id}
          });
```

Thank you a lots

Comment: `data.flatMap(({ children }) => Object.values(children));` This is definitely a duplicate, just looking for the appropriate dupe target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below:

```js
const data = [ { id: 1, name: "Beauty", children: { 0: { id: 5, parent_id: 1, name: "Dermatology", code: "dermatology", status: 1, updated_at: 1678262275, created_at: 1678262275, }, 1: { id: 7, parent_id: 1, name: "Plastic surgery", code: "plastic_surgery", status: 1, updated_at: 1678262275, created_at: 1678262275, }, }, }, { id: 2, name: "Healthiness", children: { 0: { id: 11, parent_id: 2, name: "Ophthalmology", code: "ophthalmology", status: 1, updated_at: 1678262275, created_at: 1678262275, }, 1: { id: 13, parent_id: 2, name: "Pediatrics", code: "pediatrics", status: 1, updated_at: 1678262275, created_at: 1678262275, }, }, }, ];

let cusData = data.flatMap(({ name: parent_name, children }) =>
  Object.values(children).map(({ id, name, parent_id }) => ({
    id,
    name,
    parent_id,
    parent_name,
  }))
);

console.log(cusData);
```

I have renamed the `name` in parent level as `parent_name` after destructuring

Using [Array.prototype.flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

Comment: @tthuy, check this out !!